# Modeling smooth flat edges along the curve

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

I'm new to modeling/CG world, I'm studying by myself so I decided to try model a car, but i got some problems that I don't know how to fix properly. So here is the problem :

[image]

As stated above, some verts are way out and causes some shading problems, *Subsurf* modifier fixed a lot of them, but still seems like the car was involved in a car crash or something. I've tried some things like :

- Sculpt mode with smooth brush. It helps, but is easy to mess another vertex trying to fix a couple.
- Relax tool in "edge loops" addon. It was cool but also didn't fix all the problems.
- Manually fix vert by vert. It went good in lowering the polygons but not usefull fixing many problems herer

So having this in mind I was wondering if there's a tool that can help me fixing this problem, I searched something about drawing a grease line above the object expecting some miracle to align the curve properly (xD dreams).

Or there's a technique I should search for? I'm up to learn something. I know I'll face this problem making curves in future again, so I want to learn how to handle it properly.

Thank you guys.

Comment: This may eventually be of use too http://topologyguides.com/

Answer (score 1):

The idea about subsurf modifier is that you use fewer well positioned vertices in your lowpoly mesh and let the modifier smooth inbetween. You have unneeded polygons at some spots that hinder the smoothing, and at other spots you don't have enough detail in your mesh.

Generally if you want a clean model you need to take more attention to topology. If you want to clean it (also for academic reasons) then search for "retopology", which is mostly used in creating a good lowpoly mesh for sculpted human faces.

You can also use sharp edges for more control about the subsurf modifier, very useful if you want some edges to stay unsmoothed without adding a lot of detail in the lowpoly mesh.

Comment: Thank you friend, i'm reading some stuff about retopology and some concepts are helping me to fix it. I'm trying now to low poly and keep only needed poly.

Answer (score 0):

I notice 2 ngons in your issue-areas(non-quad faces (less or more than 4 vertices per face)) .
You should try removing them (converting them to quads(often a manual process)) first and reevaluate your shading issue then. 
Subsurf and ngons (and poles) usually don't go that well together.
Take a look at this image: http://www.daystodev.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/polygons-800x238.png

Comment: I see now,i thought n-gons are only 5+ faces, i'll fix it. Thank you for clarify this for me